# VB.Net Custom Bitmap

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, search, bitmap

Its a bit complicated and I will try my best to explain what I want to achieve.

I've already worked a bit with bitmaps and copy from screen functions.
This all worked very well. But these bitmaps are always rectangles and I would like to use my own bitmap if possible.

**As an example:**

Somewhere at position x, y on my screen is a map
This map has several paths and junctions.
There are also houses and things that don't interest me, I only focus on the paths in between.

Now I want to scan this map for Argb Pixels using a bitmap and Copy from screen function. I have already done this and it works great, but instead of only scanning the paths for pixels, the whole map is scanned for pixels. But I only want these paths to be scanned.

I have this map as a template and could make a screenshot of it. Can I now import this map into Photoshop, color the houses and everything that I don't need black and make the paths transparent and import them as bitmap so that the Copy From Screen function only scans the paths or is that even possible? I haven't found anything for vb.net if someone could lead me in a right direction I would be very thankful :)

This is the code I got so far - simple pixelsearch function:

```vb
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim xd3 = Color.FromArgb(255, 100, 100, 100) 'Searching for this color on the screen

    Dim b As New Bitmap(2210, 1100)  'Position of Bitmap
    Dim g As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(b)
    g.CopyFromScreen(Me.Left, Me.Top, 0, 0, b.Size) 'Searching on Screen

    For i = 0 To (Me.Width - 0) 'searching each pixel
        For j = 0 To (Me.Height - 0) 'searching each pixel
            If b.GetPixel(i, j) = xd3 Then 'If pixel has same color that im searching for it will show a messagebox true
                MessageBox.Show("true")
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to make your question simpler and more concise. It is unclear to me what you want to do (both in principle and technically).

Comment: Your question is too broad as it stands.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it thank you